# wifi driver does not work in mi notebook 14 horizon edition with ubuntu 20.04lts

Tags: drivers, wireless, atheros

wifi driver does not work. Not able to ENABLE network.

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 32)
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [11ad:0847]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
08:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Toshiba Corporation Device [1179:011a]
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy1: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no


lshw -C network
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network DISABLED        
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: wlp7s0
       version: 32
       serial: e4:aa:ea:4f:93:cd
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=5.4.0-37-generic firmware=WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00140-QCARMSWPZ-1 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:139 memory:b6000000-b61fffff

iwconfig
wlp7s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on

dmesg | grep ath
[    1.864696] systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/dbus.socket:5: ListenStream= references a path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket → /run/dbus/system_bus_socket; please update the unit file accordingly.
[    2.618394] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.628277] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: pci irq msi oper_irq_mode 2 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[    2.920468] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: qca6174 hw3.2 target 0x05030000 chip_id 0x00340aff sub 11ad:0847
[    2.920470] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: kconfig debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[    2.920934] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: firmware ver WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00140-QCARMSWPZ-1 api 6 features wowlan,ignore-otp,mfp crc32 29eb8ca1
[    2.984444] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: failed to fetch board data for bus=pci,vendor=168c,device=003e,subsystem-vendor=11ad,subsystem-device=0847 from ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board-2.bin
[    2.984603] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: board_file api 1 bmi_id N/A crc32 ed5f849a
[    3.056775] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: unsupported HTC service id: 1536
[    3.075615] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: htt-ver 3.60 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1
[    4.096120] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: suspend timed out - target pause event never came
[    4.176808] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x6c
[    4.176809] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map
[    4.176811] ath: Country alpha2 being used: 00
[    4.176811] ath: Regpair used: 0x6c
[    4.182989] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0 wlp7s0: renamed from wlan0
[    4.445073] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: unsupported HTC service id: 1536
[    7.520182] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: wmi command 16387 timeout, restarting hardware
[    7.520186] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: failed to set tx-chainmask: -11, req 0x3
[    7.520304] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: failed to set arp ac override parameter: -108
[    7.520694] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: could not suspend target (-108)
[    7.600517] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: cannot restart a device that hasn't been started
[    7.832854] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: unsupported HTC service id: 1536
[   11.104226] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: wmi command 16387 timeout, restarting hardware
[   11.104238] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11
[   11.104793] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: could not suspend target (-108)
[   11.190363] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: cannot restart a device that hasn't been started
[   11.422552] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: unsupported HTC service id: 1536
[   14.688686] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: failed to ping firmware: -110
[   14.688697] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: failed to reset rx filter: -110
[   14.769190] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: Could not init core: -110
[   21.922589] audit: type=1107 audit(1593027220.374:46): pid=674 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.12" pid=1876 label="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" peer_pid=676 peer_label="unconfined"
[   25.237403] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: unsupported HTC service id: 1536
[   28.512335] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: htt version request timed out
[   28.512338] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: failed to setup htt: -110
[   28.592881] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: Could not init core: -110
[   28.813011] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: unsupported HTC service id: 1536
[   31.840518] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: failed to ping firmware: -110
[   31.840527] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: failed to reset rx filter: -110
[   31.920509] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: Could not init core: -110
[   42.479003] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: unsupported HTC service id: 1536
[   45.708686] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: htt version request timed out
[   45.708693] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: failed to setup htt: -110
[   45.795959] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: Could not init core: -110
[   46.028670] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: unsupported HTC service id: 1536
[   49.326970] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: wmi command 16387 timeout, restarting hardware
[   49.326983] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: failed to enable PMF QOS: -11
[   49.327446] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: could not suspend target (-108)
[   49.409149] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: cannot restart a device that hasn't been started
[   59.612848] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: unsupported HTC service id: 1536
[   62.685184] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: wmi command 16387 timeout, restarting hardware
[   62.685197] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: failed to enable PMF QOS: -11
[   62.685749] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: could not suspend target (-108)
[   62.767883] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: cannot restart a device that hasn't been started
[   62.998845] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: unsupported HTC service id: 1536
[   66.272869] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: htt version request timed out
[   66.272876] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: failed to setup htt: -110
[   66.355005] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: Could not init core: -110
[   76.545864] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: unsupported HTC service id: 1536
[   79.747540] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: failed to ping firmware: -110
[   79.747550] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: failed to reset rx filter: -110
[   79.829739] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: Could not init core: -110
[   80.059469] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: unsupported HTC service id: 1536
[   83.321152] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: failed to ping firmware: -110
[   83.321158] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: failed to reset rx filter: -110
[   83.406298] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: Could not init core: -110
[   93.502969] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: unsupported HTC service id: 1536
[   96.614717] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: failed to ping firmware: -110
[   96.614726] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: failed to reset rx filter: -110
[   96.695601] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: Could not init core: -110
[   96.923325] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: unsupported HTC service id: 1536
[  100.197090] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: wmi command 16387 timeout, restarting hardware
[  100.197094] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: failed to disable burst: -11
[  100.197555] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: could not suspend target (-108)
[  100.277860] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: cannot restart a device that hasn't been started
```

Comment: What do you mean by "installing wifi adapter"? Please [edit] your question and add more details. Is the question about a built-in wireless adapter?

Comment: Yes my network is always DISABLED. tried many things but its not ENABLING. currently uses atheros QCA6174 driver.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: Added please check

Comment: All looks good. Please also add output of `dmesg | grep ath`

Comment: added. please check

Answer (score 0):

By some research i have found the solution.
[follow link](https://www.reddit.com/r/SurfaceLinux/comments/9t53gq/wifi_fixed_on_surface_go_ubuntu_1810/)

This fixed my problem. Thanks to the auther

Comment: The solution seems to be older version of ubuntu, what addition or changes you did to apply the solution to ubuntu 20.04